# Run spreadsheets app with mono in ubuntu

Tags: linux, mono, ubuntu-14.04, spreadsheet

I'm trying to run the following app:

```
https://bulkpdf.de
```

Using ubuntu and mono. I will integrate it with wordpress.

However, when I call the app with terminal I get the following error:

```
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v4.0.30319
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper___emul_fconv_to_ovf_i8(double)
  at SpreadsheetLight.SLSimpleTheme.CalculateRowColumnInfo () [0x002df] in <da781758b9a04290acccf3dbb454ad9d>:0 
  at SpreadsheetLight.SLSimpleTheme..ctor (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WorkbookPart wbp, SpreadsheetLight.SLThemeTypeValues themetype, System.Boolean ThrowExceptionsIfAny) [0x00048] in <da781758b9a04290acccf3dbb454ad9d>:0 
  at SpreadsheetLight.SLDocument.InitialiseStylesheetWhatNots (SpreadsheetLight.SLThemeTypeValues ThemeType) [0x00000] in <da781758b9a04290acccf3dbb454ad9d>:0 
  at SpreadsheetLight.SLDocument.OpenExistingSpreadsheet (System.String SheetNameOnOpen) [0x00052] in <da781758b9a04290acccf3dbb454ad9d>:0 
  at SpreadsheetLight.SLDocument..ctor (System.IO.Stream SpreadsheetStream) [0x00099] in <da781758b9a04290acccf3dbb454ad9d>:0 
  at BulkPDF.Spreadsheet.Open (System.String filePath) [0x00011] in <38b86a5d69f64782bf8c88f7d49916c3>:0 
  at BulkPDF.MainForm.OpenSpreadsheet (System.String filePath) [0x00000] in <b6568e6b1369411392ff3ce4698bc951>:0 
  at BulkPDF.MainForm.bSelectSpreadsheet_Click (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0006e] in <b6568e6b1369411392ff3ce4698bc951>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x00019] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x0001e] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mevent) [0x00069] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mevent) [0x00000] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmLButtonUp (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00078] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x001b4] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00037] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x0000b] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (System.IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Msg msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) [0x00085] in <33c9ef2431ee44bfb02f81d92160d180>:0
```

What can I do???

Comment: That is a Windows only native call : `System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc` and is not going to work on Mono running on Ubuntu

Comment: So I have no other choice besides using windows??